# How to glow the minimum. maximum and close button?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I followed below guide to create a custom Aero Frame using DWM API.

[Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

My work:

```
void CMainFrame::OnActivate(UINT nState,CWnd* pWndOther,BOOL bMinimized )
{
    CFrameWnd::OnActivate(nState,pWndOther,bMinimized);
    BOOL fDwmEnabled = FALSE;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&fDwmEnabled)))
    {
        if(nState == WA_ACTIVE )
        {
            MARGINS margins ={-1};
            HRESULT hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd, &margins);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr));
        }
    }
}

void CMainFrame::OnNcPaint(){
    RECT rcClient;
    GetWindowRect(&rcClient);
    // Inform the application of the frame change.
    SetWindowPos( 
             NULL, 
             rcClient.left, rcClient.top,
             RECTWIDTH(rcClient), RECTHEIGHT(rcClient),
             SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    CFrameWnd::OnNcPaint();
    CDC* dc = GetWindowDC();
    dc->FillSolidRect(0,0,RECTWIDTH(rcClient),RECTHEIGHT(rcClient),RGB(0,0,0));
}

 LRESULT CMainFrame::OnNcHitTest(CPoint p)
 {
    LRESULT r ;
    r = CFrameWnd::OnNcHitTest( p);      
    if(r == HTMINBUTTON || r == HTMAXBUTTON || r == HTCLOSE)
        return r;
    else
        r = HitTestNCA(m_hWnd,p); // this function is direct copied from above link.
     return r;
 }
```

Result:

[image]

I found out the minimum, maximum and close button that will not be glowed when I move the mouse on these buttons.

[image]

General situation:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Best Regards,

Comment: You have to track mouse movements and do it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DwmDefWindowProc` is required to handle caption buttons. From [msdn:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#hittest)

> For caption button hit testing, DWM provides the `DwmDefWindowProc`
>   function. To properly hit test the caption buttons in custom frame
>   scenarios, messages should first be passed to `DwmDefWindowProc` for
>   handling. `DwmDefWindowProc` returns `TRUE` if a message is handled and
>   `FALSE` if it is not. If the message is not handled by `DwmDefWindowProc`,
>   your application should handle the message itself or pass the message
>   onto `DefWindowProc`.

In MFC it can work out as follows:

```
LRESULT cframeWnd::OnNcHitTest(CPoint p)
{
    BOOL dwm_enabled = FALSE;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&dwm_enabled)))
    {
        LRESULT result = 0;
        if (!DwmDefWindowProc(m_hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MAKELPARAM(p.x, p.y), &result))
            result = HitTestNCA(m_hWnd, p);

        if (result == HTNOWHERE && GetForegroundWindow() != this)
        {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }

        return result;
    }

    return CWnd::OnNcHitTest(p);
}
```

I added a fix with `GetForegroundWindow()`, because the `HitTestNCA` function from MSDN example is wrong, it doesn't return `HTCLIENT` when it should. So when another window has focus, it won't switch windows upon mouse click in client area.

Also, there is a leak in `OnNcPaint`:

```
CDC* dc = GetWindowDC();
```

Whenever `GetWindowDC()` is called it should be followed by `ReleaseDC`. Or just use `CWindowDC` which has automatic cleanup. You don't actually need to override `OnNcPaint` because frame has been extended to "client area".

Here is a full example:

```
class cglassWnd : public CWnd
{
    void    OnNcCalcSize(BOOL, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR*);
    LRESULT OnNcHitTest(CPoint p);
    void    OnNcMouseLeave();
    int     OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    void    OnActivate(UINT state, CWnd* otherWnd, BOOL minimized);
    void    OnPaint();
    CRect   borders;
    int     titlebar_height;
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    cglassWnd();
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(cglassWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_NCHITTEST()
    ON_WM_NCCALCSIZE()
    ON_WM_NCMOUSELEAVE()
    ON_WM_ACTIVATE()
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

cglassWnd::cglassWnd()
{
    BOOL dwm_enabled = FALSE;
    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&dwm_enabled);
    if (!dwm_enabled)
        TRACE("Error: don't use this class, add error handling...");

    //modified height for the new title bar
    titlebar_height = 60;
}

int cglassWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    int res = CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct);

    //find border thickness
    borders = { 0,0,0,0 };
    if (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_THICKFRAME)
    {
        AdjustWindowRectEx(&borders,
            GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
        borders.left = abs(borders.left);
        borders.top = abs(borders.top);
    }
    else if (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_BORDER)
    {
        borders = { 1,1,1,1 };
    }

    //Extend caption in to client area
    MARGINS margins = { 0 };
    margins.cyTopHeight = titlebar_height;
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd, &margins);

    SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    return res;
}

void cglassWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    //paint titlebar area (this used to be the non-client area)
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    rc.bottom = titlebar_height;

    //see MSDN reference for explanation of this code
    //upside-down bitmap is for the sake of DrawThemeTextEx
    CDC memdc;
    memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER infhdr = { sizeof(infhdr), rc.right, -rc.bottom, 1, 32 };
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(dc,(BITMAPINFO*)(&infhdr),DIB_RGB_COLORS,0,0,0);
    auto oldbitmap = memdc.SelectObject(hbitmap);

    //do extra titlebar painting here
    //for example put DrawThemeTextEx for window's name

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), &memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    memdc.SelectObject(oldbitmap);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);

    //begin normal paint
    //The new client area begins below titlebar_height which we define earlier
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    rc.top = titlebar_height;
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rc, RGB(128, 128, 255));
}

void cglassWnd::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL validate, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR* sz)
{
    if (validate)
    {
        sz->rgrc[0].left += borders.left;
        sz->rgrc[0].right -= borders.right;
        sz->rgrc[0].bottom -= borders.bottom;
    }
    else
    {
        CWnd::OnNcCalcSize(validate, sz);
    }
}

LRESULT cglassWnd::OnNcHitTest(CPoint pt)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;
    //handle close/minimize/maximize button
    if (DwmDefWindowProc(m_hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y), &result))
        return result;

    //cursor is over the frame or client area:
    result = CWnd::OnNcHitTest(pt);
    if (result == HTCLIENT)
    {
        ScreenToClient(&pt);
        if (pt.y < borders.top) return HTTOP;
        if (pt.y < titlebar_height) return HTCAPTION;
    }
    return result;
}

void cglassWnd::OnNcMouseLeave()
{
    //This is for close/minimize/maximize/help buttons
    LRESULT result;
    DwmDefWindowProc(m_hWnd, WM_NCMOUSELEAVE, 0, 0, &result);
    CWnd::OnNcMouseLeave();
}

void cglassWnd::OnActivate(UINT state, CWnd* otherWnd, BOOL minimized)
{
    CWnd::OnActivate(state, otherWnd, minimized);
    Invalidate(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: it seems in Win10, OnNcHitTest is not called for the extended client area (aka, the title bar).  Is it possible this is an optimization which breaks this code?

Comment: @Dan `OnNcHitTest` does get called in the example I posted

Comment: @Barkmak, thanks for replying.  I found it did not get called except for the left, right, and bottom borders.  I will double check.

Comment: I am using your code pretty much verbatim with a simple frame and view.  On debugging, it never hits the nchittest for the titlebar area or top border.  It's as if the CWnd knows that is no longer NC area, and thus doesn't even check nchittest. What am I missing?