# An Aero caption title bar issue using DWM API on the windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, aero, dwm

In order to draw the icon on the caption title bar, I have refereed [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195.aspx) and used DWM API to create my customize client area by calling DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea.

my code:

```
CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    BOOL fDwmEnabled = FALSE;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&fDwmEnabled)))
        TRACE0("DWM is enabled\n");

    TCHAR szLogoPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName ( GetModuleHandle(NULL), szLogoPath, _countof(szLogoPath)     );
    PathRemoveFileSpec ( szLogoPath );
    PathAppend ( szLogoPath, _T("lena.bmp") );
    m_pLogoImage = m_pLogoImage->FromFile ( CT2CW(szLogoPath) );
    if(NULL == m_pLogoImage)
        TRACE0("load image fail\n");
}

void CMainFrame::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL bCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* lpncsp)
{
    int xFrame = 2; 
    int yFrame = 2; 
    int nTHight = 30; 
    NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS * p; 
    RECT * rc; 
    RECT aRect;
    RECT bRect;
    RECT acRect;
    p = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *)lpncsp; 
    
    CopyRect(&bRect,&p->rgrc[1]); 
    CopyRect(&aRect,&p->rgrc[0]);

    acRect.left = aRect.left + xFrame;
    acRect.top = aRect.top - nTHight;
    acRect.right = aRect.right - xFrame;
    acRect.bottom = aRect.bottom - yFrame;
    CopyRect(&p->rgrc[0],&acRect);
    CopyRect(&p->rgrc[1],&aRect);
    CopyRect(&p->rgrc[2],&bRect);
    CFrameWnd::OnNcCalcSize(TRUE, lpncsp);
}

 LRESULT CMainFrame::OnNcHitTest(CPoint p)
 {
    BOOL dwm_enabled = FALSE;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&dwm_enabled)))
    {
        LRESULT result = 0;
        if (!DwmDefWindowProc(m_hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MAKELPARAM(p.x, p.y), &result))
            result = HitTestNCA(m_hWnd, p);

        if (result == HTNOWHERE && GetForegroundWindow() != this)
        {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }

        return result;
    }

    return CWnd::OnNcHitTest(p);
 }

BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if(cs.hMenu!=NULL)
    {
    ::DestroyMenu(cs.hMenu);    
        cs.hMenu = NULL ;    
    }
    if( !CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
        return FALSE;
    // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
    //  the CREATESTRUCT cs
    cs.style = WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED| WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME;
    cs.dwExStyle &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(0);

    return TRUE;
}

void CMainFrame::OnActivate(UINT nState,CWnd* pWndOther,BOOL bMinimized )
{
    CFrameWnd::OnActivate(nState,pWndOther,bMinimized);
    BOOL fDwmEnabled = FALSE;
    if (SUCCEEDED(DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&fDwmEnabled)))
    {
        if(nState == WA_ACTIVE )
        {
            MARGINS margins = {-1};
            /*margins.cyTopHeight = 30;
            margins.cxLeftWidth = 0;
            margins.cxRightWidth = 0;
            margins.cyBottomHeight = 0;*/
            HRESULT hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd, &margins);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
               TRACE0("Failed in DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea\n");
        }
    }
}

void CMainFrame::OnNcPaint()
{
    CFrameWnd::OnPaint();
    CDC* dc = GetWindowDC();
    RECT rcClient;
    GetWindowRect(&rcClient);
    dc->FillSolidRect(0,0,RECTWIDTH(rcClient),RECTHEIGHT(rcClient),RGB(255,0,0));

    CPaintDC gdc(this); // device context for painting
    Graphics gr(gdc.m_hDC);
    gr.DrawImage ( m_pLogoImage, 0, 0 );
    ReleaseDC(dc);

}
```

The result under Windows 7 is fine.
[image]

However, my window appears another unknown caption title bar under Windows 10.
[image]

[image]

I found out the unknown caption is caused by WS_THICKFRAME in the cs.style.
If I remove WS_THICKFRAME, the unknown cation bar will disappear, but I cannot resizing the border of my window. Furthermore, my program cannot capture the minimum, maximum and the close button message on my custom caption bar anymore.
I want to remove the unknown title bar without any side effect.
Does anyone could provide me a good solution or suggestion?

Best Regards,

Comment: *"Does anyone could provide me a good solution or suggestion?"* - Unless you tell us, what you need, that's probably not going to happen. You talked a lot about what you don't want, but never produced a succinct description, of what you really need.

Comment: I want to remove the unknown title bar without any side effect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`, it means frame is extended in to client area. It is no longer in ***non-client area***. So there is no need to override `OnNcPaint`, you can do all of the painting in `OnPaint`

```
void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    //paint titlebar area (this used to be the non-client area)
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    rc.bottom = titlebar_height;

    CDC memdc;
    memdc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader = { 
        sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), rc.Width(), -rc.Height(), 1, 32 };
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(
        dc, (BITMAPINFO*)(&bmpInfoHeader), DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, NULL, 0);
    auto oldbitmap = memdc.SelectObject(hbitmap);

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rc.Width(), rc.Height(), &memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    memdc.SelectObject(oldbitmap);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);

    //begin normal paint
    //The new client area begins below titlebar_height which we define earlier
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    rc.top = titlebar_height;
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rc, RGB(0, 0, 255));

    Gdiplus::Image *image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"file.jpg");
    Gdiplus::Graphics gr(dc);
    gr.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    delete image;
}
```

Use a member variable `CRect m_border` to keep track of border's thickness. You can use `AdjustWindowRectEx` to find the thickness of the borders.

```
void CMainFrame::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnActivate(nState, pWndOther, bMinimized);

    titlebar_height = 100;
    //find border thickness
    if (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_THICKFRAME)
    {
        m_border = { 0,0,0,0 };
        AdjustWindowRectEx(&m_border, GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd,
                GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
        m_border.left = abs(m_border.left);
        m_border.top = abs(m_border.top);
    }
    else if (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_BORDER)
    {
        m_border = { 1,1,1,1 };
    }
    else
    {
        m_border = { 0,0,0,0 };
    }

    //Extend frame in to client area
    MARGINS margins = { 0 };
    margins.cyTopHeight = titlebar_height; //<<=== *** edited
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd, &margins);
    SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}
```

`m_border` will be for example `{7,7,7,7}`;

Allow Windows to do the painting on left, right, bottom border. The top border is the only one changed

```
void CMainFrame::OnNcCalcSize(BOOL validate, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS FAR* lpncsp)
{
    if (validate)
    {
        lpncsp->rgrc[0].left += m_border.left;
        lpncsp->rgrc[0].right -= m_border.right;
        lpncsp->rgrc[0].bottom -= m_border.bottom;
    }
    else
    {
        CFrameWnd::OnNcCalcSize(validate, lpncsp);
    }
}
```

see also [How to glow the minimum. maximum and close button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802940)

Comment: I have tried it, but my program cannot capture the minimum, maximum and the close button message.

Comment: You had asked a similar question earlier and supposedly you got it right. I added a full example, see the link. The only different is that I added an example where the titlebar has fixed height, for example 60 pixels. But in your version it seems you want the whole window to act as titlebar, in that case change `titlebar_height` to max screen height, `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA....)` Don't add override for `OnNcPaint`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, when using this method the "windows drawn" borders are partially transparent.  A normal window will have a 1 pixel solid border (ignoring the transparent shadow area).  But this results in a semi-trransparent border, which results in odd looking results from alt-printscreen. Thoughts?